# How to load a excel file which having header in two rows using pentaho

Tags: pentaho

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWugC.jpg)

i have an excel file which having the header in two rows( first column header in second row and remaining columns header in 1st n 2nd row) as shown in image.

i have to load this excel into a table using pentaho.

please let me know how to load.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you define a cell block to read from, either implicitly (top left) or explicitly (giving offsets on the Sheets tab).  You can tell Spoon that you want the first row of that block treated as a header row containing fieldnames.  This allows you to populate the field list (button Get Fields) at design-time - a convenience feature.

If the names don't suite you, just change them.